# Shen and curried S-expressions

Tags: currying, shen

Are functions in Shen uniadic or variadic? Is `(+ 1 2 3)` in Shen shorthand for `(+ 1 (+ 2 3))`? I am curious about currying in Shen, and how it works together with S-expressions.

**edit**
After I have played around with the REPL, I believe functions are uniadic. I am impressed by the pattern matching, but can not understand how to write a function that behaves as `+` if I call it with more than two operands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions arent variadic, but some macros are.

```
(0-) (and true true true)
true

(1-) (macroexpand [and true true true])
[and true [and true true]]

(2-) (macroexpand [+ 1 2 3])
[+ 1 [+ 2 3]]
```

See **defmacro** for creating new ones:

http://www.shenlanguage.org/learn-shen/macros.html